# How to build with buildroot several similar configurations without rebuilding same packages?

Tags: configuration, buildroot

I have several very similar configurations which I need to build with buildroot.
But this means I need to rebuild most of same packages several times?

For example I do build x86 image bootable image.
For that I have one configuration for initramfs and second configuration for nearly same main rootfs.

Or other example, my bootable image which I do with buildroot uses Grub but also I want to generate mostly same image but IsoLinux.
Is it ever possible to avoid build procedure duplication?
How to do?

Comment: This is unsupported, but deleting the neccessary stamp files and the rootfs folder then replacing the .config file and restarting the build may produce a different image.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, even one package changes cause the configuration to change! What I suggest is to use two configurations, both with the ccache enabled and to build out-of-tree to prevent the overwrite. Check both [here](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_building_out_of_tree) and [here](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#ccache)!

With this solution, I managed to build a similar configuration in a safe and fast way!